# add values of a column from a grid in view mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

This is the code that I am using in my view of MVC C#. I have many tables like Cost. I need help with how can I add all the values from column Cost which I am adding by using the add button and that values are saving into the database. I am viewing the values in the following grid

```
function getList(id){
var listId = $(#currentId).val();
resetDatatable();c
$ajax({
url : '@Url.Action("GetList", "Controller")',
data : {
listId : listId,
id: id
},
async: true,
success : function(result){
$('mainGrid').Datable({
data:result,
responsive : true,
processing : true,
info : true,
search : true,
sort : true,
stateSave : true,
destroy : true,
bFilter : true,
order : [[1, "asc"]],
lengthMenu: [[50, 100, 200, -1],[50, 100, 200, "All"]],
columns:
[{ title: "",
visible: true,
searchable: false,
sortable: false,
"render": function(data, type, row, meta){
var cosId = row.cosId;
return data;
}},
{title: "Cost",
visible: true,
searchable: true,
sortable: true,
"render": function(data, type, row, meta){
if(row.Cost != null){
return '$' + row.Cost;
}else{return "";}
}}}}
```